# In AWS Device Farm if camera goes black, what it means?

Tags: cordova, preview, aws-device-farm, cordova-plugin-camera

I made an app using cordova and "cordova-plugin-camera-preview" plugin. I tried to test it on AWS Device Farm but the screenshots where the plugin supposed to show video-capture is black, when the tests finishes it does not shows me errors.

What does it mean?

These are the two functions I'm using to get video capture (That works on my phone):

```
function captura_video() {
            try{     

                window.canvas_video_temp = document.createElement("canvas");
                window.contexto_video_temp = canvas_video_temp.getContext("2d");

                var promisifiedOldGUM = function(constraints) {
                    var getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

                    if(!getUserMedia) {
                        return Promise.reject(new Error('Este dispositivo no esta preparado para el manejo de camara'));
                    }

                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
                    });
                }

                if(navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices = {};
                }

                if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = promisifiedOldGUM;
                }

                window.videoElement = document.getElementById("pantalla_video");

                navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia(window.constraints)
                .then(
                    stream => {
                        window.videoElement.srcObject=stream;
                        window.videoElement.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                            if(window.interruptor_buscador == true){
                                auxiliar_1();
                            }else if(window.interruptor_enlace == true){
                                auxiliar_2();
                            }
                            window.videoElement.play();
                            bucle_cuadros();
                        };
                    }
                ).catch(
                    err => {
                        alert("Error mediaDevices: " + err.code);
                    }
                );
            }catch(err2){
                alert("Error de captura de video: " + err2.message);
            }
        }


        function bucle_cuadros(){
            try{
                if (window.videoElement.readyState === window.videoElement.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
                    //SOME DIRTY THINGS HERE
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(bucle_cuadros);
            }catch(err){
                alert("Error bucle_captura: " + err.message);
            }
        }
```

And this is the screenshot provided by AWS Device Farm:
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: I think that Device Farm devices are kept in steel cases to control/limit wifi and other radio factors. So, that is probably an accurate picture of what the camera can see (which is the inside of an unlit box). The online FAQ says _"Yes, you can use the device cameras, both front- and rear-facing. Due to the way the devices are mounted, images and videos may look dark and blurry"_.

Comment: Thank you John but I made some tests with available devices and it seems that Huawei devices shows the error "alert("Error mediaDevices: " + err.code);" of my code with a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you taking screenshots or taking photos from the camera?

https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faqs/

> Q: Can I use the device camera?
>
> Yes, you can use the device cameras, both front- and rear-facing. Due to the way the devices are mounted, images and videos may look dark and blurry.

I think this image would be expected in Device Farm right now.

HTH

-James

Comment: You can use the camera but can not take real picture or scan QR code or similar things. Just it gives you an option to check camera function is working or not.